# Make border-bottom span width of center aligned text

Tags: css, html, center

I want my `p` text to have a dotted line beneath it that spans the width of the text, I would also like the `p` to be centered horizontally.

The text never be longer than one line but it will vary in length on that line (if it was totally fixed, I could solve this easily).

I can't quite figure out the solution. I have the following structure:

```
<div class="container">

    <div class="content">

        <p>This is the title</p>

    </div>

</div>
```

In my CSS, I have something like this:

```
        .container      {
                    width: 650px;
                    height: 100px;
                    }

    .content    {
                    text-align: center;
                    text-transform: uppercase;
                    font-size: 26px;
                    color: #4D4D4D;
                    }

        p           {
                    border-bottom: #808080;
                    border-bottom-width: thin;
                    border-bottom-style: dotted;            
                    }
```

Comment: Want this http://jsfiddle.net/vydT5/ ???

Answer (score 11):

Here: http://jsfiddle.net/DqFp7/

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">

    <div class="content">

        <p>This is the title</p>

    </div>

</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container {
    width: 650px;
    height: 100px;
}

.content {
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 26px;
    color: #4D4D4D;
}

p {
    border-bottom: #808080;
    border-bottom-width: thin;
    border-bottom-style: dotted;  
    display:inline;    
}​
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `text-decoration` couples with `text-decoration-style`, although support for this feature is still somewhat poor (Aug-2018: Not supported in Safari and Edge).

It's in the [spec](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-text-decor-3/#text-decoration-style), so it will eventually be supported.

.

**Example:**

```css
.container,
.content {
  width: 100%;
}

.content p {
  font-size: 30px;
  text-decoration: underline;
  text-decoration-style: dotted;
  text-decoration-color: red;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="content">
    <p>This is the title</p>
  </div>
</div>
```